# Проблемы с мышкой и пк

Tags: мышь, электроника

На пк возникла проблема с мышкой: когда нажимаю левую кнопку на рабочем столе, то открывается контекстное меню, которое открывается на правую. Иногда не даёт переключиться между окнами, на альт+таб работает. В некоторых программах клавиши на мыши всё таки нажимаются, могут перестать нажиматься, а могут сделать что-то похожее из первого предложения
Пробовал подключить новую мышь - то же самое
Пробовал почистить пк от вирусов - то же самое
Пробовал его перезагрузить - то же самое
Пробовал отключить интернет, мало ли на удалёнке кто-то подключился - то же самое
Пробовал обновить драйвера - то же самое
Уже думаю мб проц решил так странно помереть...

Answer (score 1):

Параметры - Устройства - Мышь

Выбор основной кнопки -> Левая

У вас в Windows кто-то изменил настройки вашей мыши. Именно поэтому ничего не помогает, потому что проблема именно в вашей системе. Найдите, где у вас расположены параметры Windows, найдите устройство "Мышь" и измените её настройку

Comment: Все параметры стоят как и стояли до всего этого, вернул на параметры по умолчанию - ничего не изменилось

Comment: @darks1d6r, у вас Windows ? Вы нашли в панели управления мышь ? Попробуйте нажать правую кнопку. Правая кнопка мыши работает ? Попробуйте вашу мышь воткнуть в другой комп, если есть другой комп

Comment: Никакие изменения настроек не помогали, иногда не работали обе кнопки мыши, иногда работали, подключал еще одну мышь к этому пк - то же самое. Подключал обе мыши к другому пк - работали. Проблему решил, материнка решила, что не будет работать один usb, если не воткнут другой. Спасибо за помощь